# Issues with posting image on fb wall via graph api?

Tags: iphone, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

AI am using following code to post image on user's wall on facebook

```
NSData *imageData =UIImagePNGRepresentation(newPageView.image);
     UIImage *picture = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    NSLog(@"picture is %@",picture);
    NSMutableDictionary   *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];

        FbGraphFile *graph_file = [[FbGraphFile alloc] initWithImage:picture];

    [variables setObject:graph_file forKey:@"file"];

    [variables setObject:@"this is a test message: postPictureButtonPressed" forKey:@"message"];


    FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"/me/photos" withPostVars:variables];
```

Above code post image in photos album.how can i change it to post image on wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOur Image url"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

   [variables setObject:img forKey:@"picture"];


   FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"/me/photos" withPostVars:variables];
```

Comment: `offline_access` is a) deprecated b) not required for publishing

Comment: i have already included publish stream in my code as you can see it

Comment: @elppa Using me/feed only text content is posted.image is not posted on the wall